# gwt StackPanel replace widget

Tags: gwt

I'm using StackPanel and I wonder if there is a smart method to replace one of StackPanel child's widget by another, not modifying header. Having clicked on one of children, depending on some factors, I would like to (or not) show something another. Any sugestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowing the index of the child you want to replace (by calling `getWidgetIndex(...)` perhaps), you can replace this widget by a new one like so:

```
StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
// ... you are setting up your StackPanel etc

// when you want to replace a widget
int index = sp.getWidgetIndex(widgetYouWantToReplace);
if (index != -1) {
  sp.insert(newWidget, index);
}
sp.remove(widgetYouWantToReplace);
```

Comment: this is not very satisfying solution, it has one annoying disadvantage. Having removed a widget, the page is always moved to the top.
Now I do something strange, I keep a list of widgets, and instead of replacing them, I just "tell" them to change their apperance :)